# sorting items using javascript method

Tags: javascript, methods, vuejs3

i am trying to use a sort method but it  keeps on telling me that filteredProducts is not defined

for the code to sort my items

```
data() {
    return {
      MovieCategory: ["Action", "Adventure", "Family", "Comedy", "All"],
      filteredProducts: [],
    };
```

```
  methods: {
    filterMovies(category) {
      if (category == "All") {
        this.filteredProducts = this.products;
      } else {
        this.filteredProducts = this.products.filter(
          (product) => product.MovieCategory === category
        );
      }
    },
```

```
  sortItems() {
      this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.MovieCategory < b.MovieCategory) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: It's most likely a binding issue, `methods: {` <--- and `methods` doesn't have a `filteredProducts`, but it's hard to say without more details.

Comment: Log the object 'this', and check whether it has the property 'filteredProducts'.

Comment: `this.filteredProducts = this.products` what is `this.products`?

Comment: Please convert the posted code to a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) (in the question itself)  with a bit more code such that the snippet can be run to demonstrate the error.

Comment: You don't need to assign a sort. It will adjust itself. So remove this.filteredProducts as beginning of the line: 'this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.sort'

Comment: `filteredProducts` is a property of the inline object returned by calling `data`. To update it as is, you would need record a reference to the object (returned by `data`) and and assign a new value to  _`reference.filteredProducts`_ instead of _`this.filteredProducts`_.  Redesigning the code may be necessary.